# convert string to date iOS ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I want convert a string to Date on iOS.

My code :

```
  <ion-slide style="height: 250px;" *ngFor="let item of meteo?.list">
    <h3>{{item?.weather[0]?.description}}</h3>
    <h2>{{item?.main?.temp}}</h2>
    <h4>{{convertTodate(item?.dt_txt) | date:'MMMM'}}</h4>
  </ion-slide>
```

My function :

```
  public convertTodate(string){
     return new Date(string).toLocaleDateString();
  }
```

But when I try :

```
InvalidPipeArgument: 'Invalide Date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

I try with this :

```
public convertTodate(string){
  let date = new Date(string).toDateString();
  return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'd MMMM y')
}
```

**UPDATE**

For convert date on iOS :

```
public convertTodate(string){
  return new Date(string.replace(/-/g, '/'));;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your pipe , there is not format with just **`'MMM'`** , change it as,

```
<h4>{{convertTodate(item?.dt_txt) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h4>
```

Comment: how does your string look like post here

Comment: Original string : **2018-12-19 12:00:00**

Comment: So the error was visible on iOS but not on Android. So I did a chain treatment and now it works on iOS :).

Comment: then it should be the format issue, change the format and see